# Why can I extend a private nested class by a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, nested

I have come across a bit of an oddity where it seems a template class can extend a private nested class.

Given the following private nested class:

```
class A {
private:
  class B {
  protected:
    void doSomething() {
      ...
    }
  };
};
```

The following does not compile, as expected:

```
class C : public A::B {
public:
  C() {
    this->doSomething();
  }
};
```

However, gcc happily seems to accept the following which compiles without a whimper and actually does call through to the method:

```
template<typename T>
class C : public A::B {
public:
  C() {
    this->doSomething();
  }
};
```

Does anyone know if this is the expected behaviour when using templates, or have I found an oddity in gcc. I am on version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) so I realise I am a bit out of date. If this is expected behaviour, I would really appreciate an explanation (or a pointer to an explanation) as it isn't what I was expecting and I'd like to know more about it.

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: FWIW, here's a compilable test case: http://ideone.com/nJiOU

Comment: This bug has already been reported - see [bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47346). (and I was about to submit similar bug report :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be a compiler error. The class is not accessible from any class that is not a *friend* of `A`, including any instantiation of a class template.

GCC 4.2.1 and 4.6 accept that code

Clang++ rejects it with the error message

```
error: 'B' is a private member of 'A'
  struct C : A::B {
```

Comeau rejects the code with a similar message

```
error: class "A::B" (declared at line 5) is inaccessible
struct C : A::B {
              ^
      detected during instantiation of class "C<T> [with T=int]"
```

Comment: Hi David. I thought it must have been a compiler issue as I could not for the life of me see what made the class template able to gain visibility on the private nested class. I did wonder if there was some template voodoo going on that I had never heard about before but it just felt too wrong for it to be right. I really appreciate you testing it on a couple of compilers as I only have access to gcc 4.4.5 at the moment so you've gone well beyond the call there. Thanks

Comment: And many thanks to you too Xeo for testing on VS. I thought it couldn't be expected behaviour... but when the compiler says one thing and you think another it makes you stop and question yourself a bit. Cheers

Comment: @Matt__E_: You can use comeau online [here](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) (this has been considered the most standard compliant compiler for a long time).

Comment: Now that is a handy link to remember. I knew Comeau was very standards compliant, but did not know that you could submit code to compile online. Cheers for that link. It may save me tearing out more hair in the future

Comment: @Matt__E_: Note that the above link is only for the compiler, it will not link nor execute the code. You can buy the compiler frontend for a rather small price ($50 if I recall correctly).